# Position of the DropDown of a ComboBox moving as I scroll down the worksheet in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a ComboBox in Excel but when I scroll down the worksheet, the dropdown list of the ComboBox gets separated from the ComboBox textbox. Sounds like it should have a simple solution but I haven't been able to find it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the ActiveX ComboBox placed on a worksheet then this is a normal behavior.

The solution is to select any cell before scrolling down or up to remove the focus of that control.